# How to use Rails I18n.t to translate an ActiveRecord attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, label

Trying to use my active record translations in config/locales/de.yml also in my views. I thought I am clever using this:

```
de:
  activerecord: 
    attributes:
      user:
        login: "Benutzerkennung"
        comment: "Bemerkungen"
```

And in my view this:

```
<%= label_tag :login, t('activerecord.attributes.user.login') %>
```

But instead of the translation value ("Benutzerkennung") I am getting the infamous
"translation missing: de, activerecord, attributes, user, login"

Has anybody got this working (not using the label translation plugin (I am wary of potential side effects), or User.humanize_attribute_name)? What am I missing? (it does work when I use "activerecord1" or something else than activerecord, so my setup seems to be fine)

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, my bad, it does work just fine. I fell in the YML formatting trap :(

To help you debug along the way, use "script/console" and the following statements:
- I18n.locale --> should output the locale you want to examine
- I18n.t('activerecord.attributes') --> should give you all the key/value pairs for your translation, if not, you made a formatting error in your YML file or it could not be found

And btw - the plugin works quite well http://github.com/iain/i18n_label/
if you don't like the result of ".human_name" (which the plugin uses), just fall back to I18n.t('your key')

Comment: Thanks, this actually pointed me towards my locale file being in config/locale instead of config/locales

Comment: Yes, you could try this the hard way, mapping it to your activerecord locale by hand. Or, you could just let Rails take care of it. As long as your yml is correct (do not forget the newline at the end of the yml file), and you create your label without giving the content attribute, it will search for a translation automatically.

Answer (score 8):

Another method:

```
<%= label_tag :login, User.human_attribute_name(:login) %>
```

Comment: This saved me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade Rails gem to v2.3.11 (I tried to use 2.3.9, but now days it is not available so I suggest you 2.3.11)!

```
gem install -v=2.3.11 rails
```

You can find this issues documented here: [Rails 2.3.9 Release notes](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/9/4/ruby-on-rails-2-3-9-released)